# Why the radar (moving) target return is not centered at zero frequency

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, radar

In Radar signal processing, one has to separate clutter(unwanted signals) from moving target signals.

The picture given below is an example of Radar Signal Power Spectrum(taken from the book Radar Systems Analysis  and Design Using MATLAB by B.R. Mahafza).
[image: Radar Signal Power Spectrum]

Why target return is coming in between 0(DC) and $f_{r}$ where $f_{r}$ is the pulse repetition frequency.

Comment: Moving target = doppler shift ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-doppler_radar

Comment: @PaulR . This is the hint. I got it.